# how to define the parent- children relation in D3?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

In the following json file, `id` is the Id number, `lv` is the level and `pid` is the parent Id number of this record. How can I build the parent-children node relation to draw a partition in D3.js?

I have already converted json file to an array by d3.json and data.map functions..

```
 [
    {
       "id": 1,
      "nam": "Ph",
      "lv": 1,
      "pid": 0
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "nam":"Pa",
      "lv1":2,
      "pid":1 
    },
    ...
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

To define the parent-children relationship, you need [d3.stratify()](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#stratify).

So, given your data structure, this is how your stratify function should be:

```
var stratify = d3.stratify()
    .id(function(d) { return d.id; })
    .parentId(function(d) { return d.pid; });
```

The function is pretty easy to use: in `id` you set the id of each node, and in `parentId` you set the parent id of each node (in your case, `id` and `pid` respectively).

Check this demo:

```js
var data =  [{"id": 1, "nam": "Ph", "lv": 1, "pid": ""},
    {"id":2, "nam":"Pa", "lv1":2, "pid":1},
  {"id":3, "nam":"Foo", "lv1":2, "pid":1},
  {"id":4, "nam":"Bar", "lv1":3, "pid":2}];
  
var stratify = d3.stratify()
    .id(function(d) { return d.id; })
    .parentId(function(d) { return d.pid; });
  
var root = stratify(data);

console.log(root);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

PS: the root node has no parent. So, remove the `0` in the `pid` of the root object.